# Rapidjson document as a member variable crashes that application

Tags: c++, rapidjson

When I use rapidjson document as member variable and do this:

```
class Test
{
     rapidjson::Document    m_jsonDocument;

public:
    void f()
    {
        // WORKS FINE
        rapidjson::Document document;
        if (document.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }").HasParseError())
            printf("ERROR PARSING JSON\n");
        else
            printf("%s\n", document["hello"].GetString());


         // BUT HERE THROWS, WHY?
         if (m_jsonDocument.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }").HasParseError())
             printf("ERROR PARSING JSON\n");
         else
            printf("%s\n", m_jsonDocument["hello"].GetString());
    }
};
```

When I call `if (m_jsonDocument.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }").HasParseError())` app crashes on line `flags_ = defaultFlags[type];` in `document.h` in CTOR `GenericValue(Type type)`. Visual Studio debugger says "Unable to read memory." for `_flags`. What is the problem? What is the difference between member variable and local variable?

---

**EDIT:** I set `f` as a callback using `setResponseCallback` [defined here](https://github.com/zaru/Cocos2DX_AdStir/blob/master/cocos2dx-sample/libs/extensions/network/HttpRequest.h) and `f` is being called as a callback using  `dispatchResponseCallbacks` [defined here](https://github.com/zaru/Cocos2DX_AdStir/blob/master/cocos2dx-sample/libs/extensions/network/HttpClient.cpp).

Comment: How do you call the function `f`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There is a call to server for JSON data, and there is a callback which is being called when response is arrived. `f` is the callback function. Does it matter?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh this is really strange. I cannot understand. I have called `f` as follows: `Test t; t.f();` and it worked. What is the difference? How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JoachimPileborg noted it should be important how I call `f();` One of the reasons he explained in details. Thanks to Joachim for directing to the right direction. Actually my problem was more stupid than Joachim could think :). The problem was that I was calling `f` when the response to my HTTP request is back (`f` was a callback function). But as far as I allocated `Test t;` in stack, therefore the memory was de-allocated and `this` was invalid in the point when the response was back. I know, that is really stupid :).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, most likely, that you when the member function pointer `f` is called it's called without an actual object, meaning that the `this` pointer in the member function is invalid. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you try to access member variables, as those accesses uses the (invalid) `this` pointer implicitly.

There are a couple of ways to solve this, the most straightforward is to use a static member function as callback, and pass an instance of the object as user-data (most callback systems allow this). Then the static member function can use the user-data object pointer to call the real function.

Something like

```
class Test
{
    ...

public:
    static void f_wrapper(Test* object)
    {
        object->f();
    }
};
```

Then do e.g.

```
Test object;
set_callback(&Test::f_wrapper, &object);
```

Take care that `object` doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: I use `coco2d::network::HttpRequest` in case if you are familiar with this. It has `setResponseCallback` which takes two arguments: `this` and a pointer to the method. (The class should inherit from Layer class.) And when the response is back the callback is being called like this: `        if (pTarget && pSelector) 
        {
            (pTarget->*pSelector)(this, response);
        }` where `pTarget` is the passed `this`, and `pSelector` is passed method. As you see it calls with `this`.

Comment: Another thing I can't understand how you can call non-static method without `this`?

Comment: @Narek If you pass `&Test::f` as a callback function, the code calling your function will happily call `Test::f` but it doesn't know it's a non-static member function and so will call it as an ordinary function, leading to this problem.

Comment: @Narek I also think you need to edit your question and add more code to show what you're doing, if possible a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: But call is being done like this: `pTarget->*pSelector` which is equivalent to `this->*pointerToF`. Doesn't it mean that I call `f` with `this`?

Comment: @Narek If `pTarget` is a pointer to an `Test` instance, then yes it should work. Have you used a debugger and looked at the call-stack to see that `pTarget` is a valid `Test` instance pointer?

Comment: I have used debugger, but it is not valid I guess :(. I have added an `EDIT` part, to describe my problem better. Also I have tested to use pointer to `rapidjson::Document` as a member variable, and I do `m_jsonDocument = new rapidjson::Document();` right before parsing and it works. Therefore, I tend to think that the problem you described is not my case. What you think?

Comment: I have found the problem. This was so stupid. I have create `Test t;` in stack, and when response was back `t` was destroyed, and, hence, it was invalid. But you helped me to go to the right direction. Thank you! :)